# How much contrast is enough to pair same classification serifs?

Tags: font-pairing

I was experimenting pairings in http://www.typeconnection.com/index.php ,specifically pairing by similarity and I'm having difficulty trying to understand why ITC Century + LinoLetter = good pairing but Adobe Garamond + Lino Letter = bad pairing.
What is the difference between those two pairings?

I seem to struggle knowing how much contrast should we be looking for two pairings to work.In terms of proportions and details comparison between letter,isn't one element of contrast enough?Should we be looking for a certain minimum number?

I should add that I've clicked on the "Send on a date" and read the explanation, I still can't understand why Adobe Garamond + Lino Letter are a bad pairing if the only reason is "extremely legible typefaces".The x-height is quite different, so I'm really not following.

Comment: Cute site. If you click on "SEND ON A DATE" they actually explain why a pair is good or bad. So I think that's your answer. Note that personal opinion plays a role in this as well.

Comment: Unfortunately even after "sending them on a date" I have difficulty understanding and especially putting it into practice in comparing other typefaces. To me,in the Adobe Garamond + Lino Letter the explanation doesn't cut it.I can't see why being "extremely legible factors" (and why are they so?) is a factor alone to make them too similar.They even have quite different x-heights.